# Executar código JavaScript em outra página a partir de um botão

Tags: javascript, html

Quando clico no botão **Simular** ele adiciona as linhas (conforme o código do JS) na mesma página...

Porém gostaria de saber o que preciso fazer para essas linhas serem geradas em outra página, ou seja, após clicar no botão ele **redireciona para outra página e gera as tabelas.**

OBS1: Os parâmetros de entrada são fornecidos pelo usuário na página onde se encontra o botão simular.

OBS2: O código JS é responsável por criar os elementos `td`

**Botão SIMULAR**

```
<button id="simular" type="button" style="margin-top: 15px;"  class="btn btn-primary" >Simular</button>
```

**TABELA A SER GERADA NA OUTRA PAGINA**

```
<table id="tabela1" border="1">
    <thead id="cabecalho">
        <th>Info A</th>
        <th>Info B</th>
        <th>Info C</th>
        <th>Info D</th>
        <th>Info E</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <td>

       </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CÓDIGO DO BOTÃO NO ARQUIVO JS**

```
botao_simular.addEventListener('click', simular);
```

**CÓDIGO JS PARA GERAR AS LINHAS**

```
function simular(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var media = campo1.value;
  if ( media >= 131 && media <= 10000) {
      nova_simulacao = new Opcao1 (campo_nome.value, campo1.value);

  } else {
      document.querySelector(".alerta").innerText = "A média deve ser maior que 130 e menor que 10.000"; 
  };
};
```

Comment: Boa tarde. O que seria esse "Outro HTML"?

Comment: Outra pagina que criei para aparecer o resultado do meu código JS. 
Porém os parametros de entrada são informados pelo usuário nessa primeira página.. quando ele clicar no simular preciso que vá para outra página onde vão aparecer os resultados.

Comment: E onde está o código da outra página?

Comment: Você precisa dos dados que o usuário digitar na outra página, é isso? Se sim, já tentou utilizar o sessionStorage?

Comment: Fechei a pergunta como "precisa de mais detalhes e esclarecimentos". Por favor, @FrancoMotta, se deseja a reabertura da pergunta, adicione mais detalhes ou mais informações do que você precisa.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters já editei e fui o mais claro possível. Se puder abrir a questão novamente agradeço, ou vou ter que fazer outra.

Comment: @Jaderson o sessionStorage devo incluir dentro do código JS do botão?

Comment: Pode ser no clique do botão... Eu criaria uma função para salvar no sessionStorage todos os dados que você precisa na outra página e também criaria uma função para recuperar esses dados. Assim você chama as funções quando for necessário. Nesse link você tem uma noção rápida de como utilizar o recurso: https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/quando-usar-sessionstorage-e-localstorage/